# Adding Button at runtime does not work

Tags: c#, wpf

I do not have no error to this code, but Form does not display button at runtime; do not know why?

Here is the code:

```
private void Btn_Admin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Button BtnTest = new Button();
        BtnTest.Name = "Test_Btn";
        BtnTest.Content = "Look";
        BtnTest.Margin = new Thickness(150, 150, 0, 0);
        BtnTest.Width = 75;
        BtnTest.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.MyGrid.Children.Add(BtnTest);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the button is outside of the visible area?

Comment: Try adding it to a single cell rather than the grid itself.

Comment: The code works. Something else is wrong.

Comment: Long time ago that I did something like this, but I give it a try, don't you need to do a refresh? base.refresh();

Comment: No, he doesn't @Cageman

Comment: I would expect the error in here: **`this.MyGrid.Children.Add(BtnTest)`** you should explain why and where you expect a Button in a Grid?

Comment: Hi Guys thank u all, i just delate the line Btntest.Margin = new Thickness() and it did work.

Answer (score 2):

Set the buttons location. And name buttons uniquely.

If you're adding buttons to a grid you're doing it wrong. You need to set the grids column to be of button type.

Comment: U musst have a container to add a control. without grid its come to a exception

Answer (score 0):

You are using a strange System.Windows.Forms Button??!
where did you get the properties like .content and Thinkness and so on?

**Also be sure your event does actually fire!**

This simple Form Class works fine:

```
    private void TestOverflowButton_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Btn_Admin();
    }

    private void Btn_Admin() {
        try {
            Button BtnTest = new Button();
            BtnTest.Name = "Test_Btn";
            BtnTest.Text = "Look";

            BtnTest.Width = 75;
            BtnTest.Visible = true;
            Controls.Add(BtnTest);

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: i use VS 2012 for deskop. somehow there are many controls and properties i use to , they not appear here

Answer (score 0):

This code all looks ok. First of all are you sure you are adding the new Button instance to the correct Grid, are there any RowDefinitions/ColumnDefinitions if yes make sure that you have set the appropriate value to those attached properties (Grid.SetRow() etc.). Second what is the type of the

```
this.MyGrid
```

Is this a simple Grid control or a DataGrid? Another interesting question that raises when looking at the provided code snippet is why are you wrapping this quite simple and straight forward code with a try/catch, are you expecting an exception to happen and if yes what exception exactly. Generally wrapping you code with a try/catch is not a good practice if you are not expecting an exception which you know how to handle as it would "eat up" all exceptions leading to unexpected behaviors.